# Git - How to edit old (not previous) commit with some of the unstaged changes from current index (current state)?

Tags: git

I've taken a look at these previous questions already:

- [Howto add a changed file to an older (not last) commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719579/howto-add-a-changed-file-to-an-older-not-last-commit-in-git)
- [How do I edit a previous git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103396/how-do-i-edit-a-previous-git-commit)

They don't exactly address a particular issue though - there are other changes in the index! When running the `rebase` command, git complains: `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.`

#### Scenario:

The commit previous to the last one (do I refer to that as "2 HEADs ago"?) was a refactor commit. I currently have in the index many unstaged changes, but only some of which I want to add to the previous to last commit.

I'm imagining the way to do this would be to:

1. `stash` all of my current changes
2. `rebase -i` to the previous to last commit (changing index and moving Head, right?)
3. load the stash into my index without changing Head (how?)
4. use `add -p` and `commit --amend` to selectively modify this old commit
5. `rebase --continue` to finish (updates children, moves Head back to where I started, what happens to index?)
6. then pop/clear the stash (index back to where I started).

Is this correct? If it is, how do I do step 3? If it isn't, what should I be doing instead?

Also, note that I'm still learning about git and am still not 100% sure I'm referencing things in git (Head, index, stash, etc) properly.

---

#### Solution:

For anyone else this may help, these are the steps I actually took:

1. `git stash` all of my current changes
2. `git rebase -i <ID>` to the *parent* of the previous to last commit, changing index and moving Head
3. `git stash apply` load the stash into my index without changing Head

   - if you have conflicts, `git reset HEAD <file>` to unload files staging. Make sure staging is clear.
4. use `add -p` and `commit --amend` to selectively stage changes and commit them
5. `git reset --hard` to discard index so it matches Head
6. `git rebase --continue` to finish. updates children, moves Head back to very start, but with changes

   - history is now forked into two versions. The other branch ends at the WIP previously stashed
7. then pop the stash to bring index back to where I started. The other branch is also cleared.

Comment: Note that you have a new option with the upcoming git1.8.4. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17284754/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plan sounds good. A `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` will modify the working tree and/or index, but will not change HEAD, so you should be able to do it while in a rebase edit.

Comment: It turns out that I also needed a `git reset --hard` between 4 and 5. If I understand it correctly, it's because the changes I didn't want to add to the old commit needed to be removed from the index to match the old commit (or else conflicts), before `rebase --continue`

Answer (score 5):

With [git1.8.4 (July 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L53-L55), you can choose to:

- rebase
- while keeping your local unstaged changes!

> "`git rebase`" learned "`--[no-]autostash`" option to save local changes instead of refusing to run (to which people's normal response was to stash them and re-run).

So in your case, this could work (and save your work in progress in the meantime):

```
git rebase --autostash -i <ID>
```

See [commit 587947750bd73544a6a99811f0ddfd64e1ff1445](https://github.com/git/git/commit/587947750bd73544a6a99811f0ddfd64e1ff1445):

> This new feature allows a rebase to be executed on a dirty worktree or index.
>   It works by creating a temporary "dangling merge commit" out of the worktree and index changes (via 'git stash create'), and automatically applying it after a successful rebase or abort.
>
> `rebase` stores the SHA-1 hex of the temporary merge commit, along with the rest of the rebase state, in either `.git/{rebase-merge,rebase-apply}/autostash` depending on the kind of rebase.
>   Since `$state_dir` is automatically removed at the end of a successful rebase or abort, so is the `autostash`.
>
> **The advantage of this approach is that we do not affect the normal stash's reflogs, making the `autostash` invisible to the end-user.
>
>   This means that you can use 'git stash' during a rebase as usual.**
>
> When the `autostash` application results in a conflict, we push `$state_dir/autostash` onto the normal stash and remove `$state_dir` ending the rebase.
>   The user can inspect the stash, and pop or drop at any time.

---

Note: git 2.0.1 (Jult 25th, 2014) handle the autostash case.
See [commit e4244eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4244eb3957d478ca05b42d8b56aadb9ab2bc7ae) from [Ramkumar Ramachandra (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon) (also in [his blog](http://artagnon.com/git-rebase.autostash)):

#### `rebase -i`: handle "Nothing to do" case with `autostash`

> When a user invokes

```
$ git rebase -i @~3
```

> with dirty files and `rebase.autostash` turned on, and exits the `$EDITOR` with an empty buffer, the autostash fails to apply.
>
> Although the primary focus of rr/rebase-autostash was to get the `git-rebase--backend.sh` scripts to return control to `git-rebase.sh`, it missed this case in `git-rebase--interactive.sh`.
>   Since this case is unlike the other cases which return control for housekeeping, assign it a special return status and handle that return value explicitly in git-rebase.sh.

---

### With the latest git, simply do `git config rebase.autostash true` to make `rebase [-i]` work in a dirty worktree.

> This new feature allows a rebase to be executed on a dirty worktree or index.
>   It works by creating a temporary "dangling merge commit" out of the worktree and index changes (via '`git stash create`'), and automatically applying it after a successful rebase or abort.
>
> rebase stores the SHA-1 hex of the temporary merge commit, along with the rest of the rebase state, in either `.git/{rebase-merge,rebase-apply}/autostash` depending on the kind of rebase. Since `$state_dir` is automatically removed at the end of a successful rebase or abort, so is the `autostash`.
>
> The advantage of this approach is that we do not affect the normal stash's reflogs, making the autostash invisible to the end-user. This means that you can use '`git stash`' during a rebase as usual.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you want to do, it's not much different than the answer on your first link, you just need to stash the changes you *don't* want to add to the older commit. You can do it like this:

1. Commit the changes you want added to your penultimate commit. Just give it a simple commit message like "add this," as it won't be around for long.
2. Stash the remaining changes that you don't want added to the commit.
3. Look up the *parent* of the commit you're adding to. For example, if the commit you want to modify has an SHA1 of `aaaaaaa` and its parent is `bbbbbbb`, you want `bbbbbbb`.
4. Do `git rebase -i bbbbbbb` (substituting the correct commit as determined in step 3). Move the most recent commit ("add this") up to just below the commit you're modifying and change it from `pick` to `fixup`. This will add it to that commit without change that commit's message.
5. Unstash the changes from step 1, and carry one from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
`git stash`
`git checkout <COMMIT HASH from 2 commits ago>`
`git stash pop`
`git add` (selectively--one file at a time)
`git commit --amend`
`git stash` (to re-stash all the changes you didn't commit)
`git branch temp`
`git checkout master`
`git rebase temp -i`
```

This will open a text editor with a list of commits--one commit per row.  Delete the first row, which is the old commit that you want to replace.  Save and close.

```
`git branch -d temp` (to clean up the branch you created)
```