# git pull on staging server failing because of local changes

Tags: git, version-control

On my staging server I have a cron job that does a `git pull` every two minutes, most of the times everything works fine, but sometimes I notice that the changes that I pushed to the repo are not pulled, when I inspect the issue and run `git pull` manually I get an error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
{the file(s) that I had pushed to the repo}
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

I don't understand how these changes are being considered "local changes". any help?

Comment: it seems that you have accidentally edited a file on your server. I would suggest verify the changes first using `git diff` then if you don't want the changes on the server you can do `git stash`

Comment: This happened several times, and the local changes are always my latest commit.

Comment: is it some specific file that it refers to every time it gives that error ? Also have a look at a [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/ignoring-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merg)

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned before ("[Cannot pull with rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18852444/6309)") that `git rebase` learned the `--autostash` option (git 1.8.5+).

You could combine that with a reset --hard in order to make sure the end result of your scheduled git upll is always a clean state:

```
git config rebase.autostash true
git pull -rebase
git reset --hard
```

That assumes you have no local commit or work in progress on the repo updated by your `git pull` (or it would be erased by the `reset --hard`)

The `autostash` option ensure that the untracked state of the working tree (for whatever reason) is not blocking the `git pull`.
And the `reset --hard` should make sure the working tree is clean.