# Can "git pull" automatically stash and pop pending changes?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

I know how to solve this:

```
user@host$ git pull
Updating 9386059..6e3ffde
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    foo.bar
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

But isn't there a way to let `git pull` do the `stash` and `pop` dance for me?

If this command has a different name, it's ok.

Creating a shell alias for `git stash; git pull; git stash pop` is a solution, but I search for a better solution.

Comment: what about a *git* alias?

Comment: Running `git stash; git pull; git stash pop` programmatically is dangerous, because if there is nothing to stash, `git stash` will be a no-op, but `git stash pop` will pop the last stash (if any), which is almost certainly *not* what you want. User torek has a great post about this on Stack Overflow, but I can't find it...

Comment: @Jubobs this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/6309 Or this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/6309

Comment: @VonC I checked both questions, and I don't think this question (mine) is a duplicate.

Comment: @VonC One of those :) Thanks.

Comment: @guettli I was not implying your question is a duplicate, I was just answering Jubobs' comment.

Comment: As a step further, the operation should succeed only if the stash can be cleanly applied after the pull.  If there are conflicts, then the whole operation fails atomically so that the tree is not changed.  This is what I would like to do: either pull down the changes with my local ones merged in, or else fail with an error and let me decide manually what to do next.  Is this kind of git 'transaction' possible?

Comment: You now have `git config merge.autostash`, if you want to pull without rebasing (while stashing your local changes automatically). See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

**For Git 2.6+ (released 28 Sept 2015)**

The <del>only</del> [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) setting which would be of interest is:

> ### `rebase.autostash`

(with Git 2.27, Q2 2020, you now also have **`merge.autostash`**, see below)

> When set to true, automatically create a temporary stash before the operation begins, and apply it after the operation ends.
> This means that you can run rebase on a dirty worktree.
>
> However, use with care: the final stash application after a successful rebase might result in non-trivial conflicts. Defaults to false.

Combine that with:

> ### `pull.rebase`

> When true, rebase branches on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull" is run.

In a given repository:

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

That would be enough for a simple `git pull` to work even in a dirty tree.
No alias needed in that case.

---

See [commit 53c76dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53c76dc05e0b5ad5b1f92db9577694e896d67a0a) (04 Jul 2015) by [Kevin Daudt (`Ikke`)](https://github.com/Ikke).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e69b408](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e69b40828070b71c423820d1e35d5fb1e5b1a550), 17 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `pull`: allow dirty tree when `rebase.autostash` enabled

> rebase learned to stash changes when it encounters a dirty work tree,
> but `git pull --rebase` does not.
>
> Only verify if the working tree is dirty when `rebase.autostash` is not
> enabled.

---

Note: if you want to pull *without* autostash (even though `rebase.autoStash true` is set), you have since git 2.9 (June 2016):

```
 pull --rebase --no-autostash
```

See [commit 450dd1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/450dd1dce1fbf6a6743e74d6aef750068fc5069c), [commit 1662297](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16622979f8eaf864da5cf932d3d60de7c7d40d7d), [commit 44a59ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44a59fff4598f3d2f68b5bc83c75e8483637a33d), [commit 5c82bcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c82bcddf4f436f137bf0608321c92b8328a270a), [commit 6ddc97c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ddc97c7dc11076be30846c13666e5bc1844629a), [commit eff960b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eff960b3afc70cb936dbf133e8c60d397d8069ac), [commit efa195d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efa195d5b3ab69b419d16b1882e8e1c0537186f5) (02 Apr 2016), and [commit f66398e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66398eb57c627169429f47bbe4d943d2c975959), [commit c48d73b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c48d73bdececb38af237450724b1a67307d7a013) (21 Mar 2016) by [Mehul Jain (`mehul2029`)](https://github.com/mehul2029).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7c137bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c137bb5316fbd82e816c2dabebc1d347261c93e), 13 Apr 2016)</sup>

[Commit f66398e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66398eb57c627169429f47bbe4d943d2c975959) in particular includes:

> ### `pull --rebase`: add `--[no-]autostash` flag

> If `rebase.autoStash` configuration variable is set, there is no way to
> override it for "`git pull --rebase`" from the command line.
>
> Teach "`git pull --rebase`" the `--[no-]autostash` command line flag which
> overrides the current value of `rebase.autoStash`, if set. As "`git rebase`"
> understands the `--[no-]autostash` option, it's just a matter of passing
> the option to underlying "`git rebase`" when "`git pull --rebase`" is called.

---

Warning: before Git 2.14 (Q3 2017), "`git pull --rebase --autostash`" didn't auto-stash when the local history fast-forwards to the upstream.

See [commit f15e7cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15e7cf5cc95cbfd0d05c260f75631781e290edc) (01 Jun 2017) by [Tyler Brazier (`tylerbrazier`)](https://github.com/tylerbrazier).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 35898ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35898eafab5dfd4ebc9daf2f4e422a1d4771954b), 05 Jun 2017)</sup>

> ### `pull`: ff `--rebase --autostash` works in dirty repo

> When `git pull --rebase --autostash` in a dirty repository resulted in a
> fast-forward, nothing was being autostashed and the pull failed.
> This was due to a shortcut to avoid running rebase when we can fast-forward,
> but autostash is ignored on that codepath.

---

Update: [Mariusz Pawelski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350384/mariusz-pawelski) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes/30209750?noredirect=1#comment88533666_30209750) an interesting question:

> So everybody is writing about `autostash` when you do rebase (or `pull --rebase`).

> But no one is taking about autostashing when you do normal pull with *merges*.
> So there is no automatic switch for that? Or I am missing something? I prefer doing `git pull --rebase` but OP asked about "*standard*" git pull

Answer:

The **[original thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg204172.html)** discussing this autostash feature, it was implemented originally both for `git pull` (merge) and `git pull --rebase`.

But... Junio C Hamano (Git maintainer) noted that:

> If the `pull-merge` were something that would induce the "annoyance"
> that triggered this topic, by definition, the local change overlaps
> with the merge, and this internal "stash pop" will touch the paths
> the merge touched and it is likely not result in "Dropped" but leave
> further conflicts to be resolved.
>
> I suspect that `pull.autostash` configuration is not a good addition because it encourages a bad, pain-inducing workflow.
> In simple cases it may not hurt, but when local changes are complex, it would actively hurt than not having it, and the configuration robs the incentive to choose.
>
> The equation is somewhat different for "pull-rebase", as "rebase"
> insists you to start from a clean working tree, so "download and
> then stop" annoyance feels bigger.  I have a suspicion that
> loosening that may be a more productive fix to the real problem.

So, regarding a classic pull-merge, it is better to:

> **encourage the user to think about the nature of WIP he has in the working tree before running "`git pull`"**.
> Is it a too complex beast that may interfere with what others are doing, or
> is it a trivial change that he can stash away and pop it back?
>
> If the former, he will be far better off doing "`checkout -b`", keep
> working until the local change gets into somewhat a better shape and
> "commit", before pulling into the original branch.
>
> If the latter, he is better off doing:

> - "`git pull`",
> - after finding it conflicts, run
>
>   - `git stash`,
>   - `git merge FETCH_HEAD` and
>   - `git stash pop`

---

That being said, with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git pull`" learned to warn when no `pull.rebase` configuration exists, and neither `--[no-]rebase` nor `--ff-only` is given (which would result a merge).

See [commit d18c950](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d18c950a69f3a24e1e3add3d9fc427641f53e12b) (10 Mar 2020) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1c56d6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c56d6f57adebf2a0ac910ca62a940dc7820bb68), 27 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d18c950a69f3a24e1e3add3d9fc427641f53e12b): warn if the user didn't say whether to rebase or to merge
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> Often novice Git users forget to say "`pull --rebase`" and end up with an unnecessary merge from upstream.
>
> What they usually want is either "`pull --rebase`" in the simpler cases, or "`pull --ff-only`" to update the copy of main integration branches, and rebase their work separately.
> The `pull.rebase` configuration variable exists to help them in the simpler cases, but there is no mechanism to make these users aware of it.
>
> Issue a warning message when no `--[no-]rebase` option from the command line and no `pull.rebase` configuration variable is given.
> This will inconvenience those who never want to "`pull --rebase`", who haven't had to do anything special, but the cost of the inconvenience is paid only once per user, which should be a reasonable cost to help a number of new users.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git merge`" learns the "`--autostash`" option, and the new `merge.autostash` setting.

See [commit d9f15d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9f15d37f1a545305988f6b2bb40de1fbf0049cf), [commit f8a1785](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8a178580719a93040a49cf25624f1d56d0147f1), [commit a03b555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a03b55530ab844974b7058042a015fcfcd9e7a53), [commit 804fe31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/804fe3155761e73c3dcc4e162ddb3ff560f16cd7), [commit 12b6e13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12b6e1367af429628dbaeaa0c7518cacc620d786), [commit 0dd562e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dd562e0f7c0bb9ca64f1a02265ff5d1be86df34), [commit 0816f1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0816f1dff8715e80b5fa0b73b48dd36ef9e1e381), [commit 9bb3dea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bb3dea45d69921578b1729c7dc7b12bfbe6f69e), [commit 4d4bc15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d4bc157f85316576d9f9bb90657d455fe76e281), [commit b309a97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b309a9710899dab2f76455526f573a90fad5d13c), [commit f213f06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f213f069fb57996505f9d6c9dd0f4a3ef53e87e4), [commit 86ed00a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353), [commit facca7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/facca7f06e7256bf15675657f59ef6f6c883aec3), [commit be1bb60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be1bb600da13523dd2d63ae93432d7f3b16ffb74), [commit efcf6cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efcf6cf0492c4a78d968c6246698d9aafae61578), [commit c20de8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c20de8bec6ba759c5e17ad8b8fd7105e8228e313), [commit bfa50c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfa50c2c7f0cb806af6d272a84c16f114e15ceee), [commit 3442c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3442c3d11df16d7cd3867b133a8ec6ddd21a8839), [commit 5b2f6d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b2f6d9cd50b1c8909326c7175aef288a9915f33) (07 Apr 2020), [commit 65c425a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65c425a2ec815989994716c81a2307ae5b5645bc) (04 Apr 2020), and [commit fd6852c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd6852cab219149e800d352f3939631377b41575), [commit 805d9ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/805d9eaf5eab0edc3567d9e19e74a3f9168e764a) (21 Mar 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bf10200](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf10200871d9e7e1fc9f54aca9b2fe40bc4e4ac7), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9f15d37f1a545305988f6b2bb40de1fbf0049cf): pass --autostash to merge
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> Before, `--autostash` only worked with `git pull --rebase`.
>
> However, in the last patch, merge learned `--autostash` as well so there's no reason why we should have this restriction anymore.
> **Teach pull to pass `--autostash` to merge, just like it did for rebase.**

And:

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353): use `apply_autostash()` from sequencer.c
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> The `apply_autostash()` function in [`builtin/rebase.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353/builtin/rebase.c) is similar enough to the `apply_autostash()` function in [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353/sequencer.c) that they are almost interchangeable, except for the type of arg they accept. Make the [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353/sequencer.c) version extern and use it in rebase.
>
> The rebase version was introduced in [6defce2b02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6defce2b02909b8e0fcf1ffeecee743688b97b49) ("builtin rebase: support `--autostash` option", 2018-09-04, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0293121717ba66f089a38ce4d4d895db0f946e49) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d582ea202b626dcc6c3b01e1e11a296d9badd730)) as part of the shell to C conversion.
> It opted to duplicate the function because, at the time, there was another in-progress project converting interactive rebase from shell to C as well and they did not want to clash with them by refactoring [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86ed00aff4b86eed6ecc606e9d5f7828a1dca353/sequencer.c) version of `apply_autostash()`.
> Since both efforts are long done, we can freely combine them together now.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the UI is improved:

See [commit e01ae2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e01ae2a4a7e99357b9464b54e48cbf4b4caac036) (19 Nov 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 290c940](https://github.com/git/git/commit/290c94085bc913951d15c47bce818a19541a1e72), 30 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e01ae2a4a7e99357b9464b54e48cbf4b4caac036): colorize the hint about setting `pull.rebase`
>
> <sup>Pointed-out-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [d18c950a69f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d18c950a69f3a24e1e3add3d9fc427641f53e12b) ("`pull`: warn if the user didn't say whether to rebase or to merge", 2020-03-09, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c56d6f57adebf2a0ac910ca62a940dc7820bb68) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a)), a new hint was introduced to encourage users to make a conscious decision about whether they want their pull to merge or to rebase by configuring the `pull.rebase` setting.
>
> This warning was clearly intended to advise users, but as pointed out in [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/87ima2rdsm.fsf%40evledraar.gmail.com), it uses `warning()` instead of `advise()`.
>
> One consequence is that the advice is not colorized in the same manner as other, similar messages.
> So let's use `advise()` instead.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), `git pull --rebase` is simplified:

See [commit a7d18a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7d18a11098b5f9cc8b1511ecaef5378c1030f97), [commit a751e02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a751e0296f6771e4dec6258d8c3f9bf658da30de), [commit 3400622](https://github.com/git/git/commit/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9) (17 Jun 2021) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 221ec24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/221ec24e9bbe35ef9ba67304828fac92e28dd2ff), 08 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9): cleanup autostash check
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> Currently "[`git pull --rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L105)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalse%7Ctrue%7Cmerges%7Cpreserve%7Cinteractive))</sup> takes a shortcut in the case a fast-forward merge is possible; `run_merge()` is called with --ff-only.
>
> However, "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> did ont have an `--autostash` option, so, when "[`git` pull `--rebase` --autostash``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L105)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalse%7Ctrue%7Cmerges%7Cpreserve%7Cinteractive))</sup> was called *and* the fast-forward merge shortcut was taken, then the pull failed.
>
> This was fixed in [commit f15e7cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15e7cf5cc95cbfd0d05c260f75631781e290edc) ("`pull`: ff `--rebase` --autostash works in dirty repo", 2017-06-01, Git v2.14.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35898eafab5dfd4ebc9daf2f4e422a1d4771954b) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3a847d1dba7688435058d8d4161b3456bc1103d)) by simply skipping the fast-forward merge shortcut.
>
> Later on "`git merge`" learned the `--autostash` option [[a03b555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a03b55530ab844974b7058042a015fcfcd9e7a53) ("`merge`: teach `--autostash` option", 2020-04-07, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf10200871d9e7e1fc9f54aca9b2fe40bc4e4ac7) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26))], and so did "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/340062243a474b8fa56f4c3f6572bf015392f7f9/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> [[d9f15d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9f15d37f1a545305988f6b2bb40de1fbf0049cf) ("`pull`: pass `--autostash` to merge", 2020-04-07, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf10200871d9e7e1fc9f54aca9b2fe40bc4e4ac7) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26))].
>
> Therefore it's not necessary to skip the fast-forward merge shortcut anymore when called with `--rebase --autostash`.
>
> Let's always take the fast-forward merge shortcut by essentially reverting [f15e7cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15e7cf5cc95cbfd0d05c260f75631781e290edc).

---

The auto-stashed local changes created by "[`git merge --autostash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a4779086deb12d406f819a619cc28924461f1a4/Documentation/merge-options.txt#L191)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---autostash))</sup> was mixed into a conflicted state left in the working tree, which has been corrected with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022).

See [commit d3a9295](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3a9295ada961012bfe8582540e40a02e772aa09) (23 Aug 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3a47790](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a4779086deb12d406f819a619cc28924461f1a4), 01 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3a9295ada961012bfe8582540e40a02e772aa09): only apply autostash when appropriate
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> If a merge failed and we are leaving conflicts in the working directory for the user to resolve, we should not attempt to apply any autostash.
>
> Further, if we fail to apply the autostash (because either the merge failed, or the user requested `--no-commit`), then we should instruct the user how to apply it later.
>
> Add a testcase verifying we have corrected this behavior.

The new instructions:

> When finished, apply stashed changes with `git stash pop`.

Comment: As of 2.4.2, this is not implemented yet.  Perhaps some day.  `rebase.autoStash` applies only when using rebase.  `pull.rebase` applies only when using pull.

Comment: "That would be enough for a simple git pull to work even in a dirty tree." As Randal commented, this isn't true yet. The current master's [pull.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/pull.c#L829) still chooses to `die_on_unclean_work_tree`.

Comment: @Pradhan I agree. The implementation just got in master this morning and should be up for git 2.6. I have edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: I have confirmed that autostash is working with git `2.5.5`.

Comment: SVN will do all that automatically.

Comment: So everybody is writing about autostash when you do `rebase` (or `pull --rebase`). But no one is taking about autostashing when you do normal `pull` with merges.
So there is no automatic switch for that? Or I am missing something? I prefer doing `git pull --rebase` but OP asked about "standard" `git pull`

Comment: @MariuszPawelski Very interesting question. I have edited my answer to explain why there is no autostash for a regular git pull (merge).

Comment: Any idea how to make this work with untracked files too?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei could you add more details to your comment, in a separate question? That will be more visible than here, buried in comments.

Answer (score 74):

To save few seconds for oncoming explorers, here is a summary (thanks to @VonC):

```
git pull --rebase --autostash
```

---

Or, if you want to set it to default (as documented in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)),

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

And then just

```
git pull
```

Comment: The point is: after a `git config pull.rebase true` and 
`git config rebase.autoStash true`, all you'll ever need is `git pull`. Just `git pull`. No other options required.

Comment: Appears you need at least Git 2.9 for the `--autostash` option. The `-c rebase.autoStash=true` works in Git 2.6 onward.

Answer (score 16):

As the comment above stated, setting the two config values doesn't currently work with `git pull`, as the autostash config only applies to actual rebases. These git commands do what you want:

```
git fetch
git rebase --autostash FETCH_HEAD
```

Or set it as an alias:

```
git config alias.pullr '!git fetch; git rebase --autostash FETCH_HEAD'
```

Then do:

```
git pullr
```

Of course, this alias can be renamed as desired.

Answer (score 7):

With Git 2.6+ you can use the following:

```
alias gup='git -c rebase.autoStash=true pull --rebase'
```

This `--rebase` makes git-pull use `rebase` instead of `merge`, so settings/options like `--ff-only` won't apply.

I am using an alias to pull with `--ff-only` by default (`git pull --ff-only`), and can then use `gup` (from above) in case a fast-forward merge is not possible or there are stashed changes.

Comment: What is the main difference between `git pull --ff-only` and `git pull pull --rebase --autostash`

Answer (score -2):

As you already mentioned this is the way to do it. You can use it in alias to save you typing and to use shortcut or you can use it in a single line (can be an alias as well)

`git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop`

It will do the same thing as you done but in a single line (&&) and is you set as alias it will even be shorter.

The following lines will display the incoming/outgoing changes before you pull/push

```
git log ^master origin/master
git log master ^origin/master
```

Comment: This approach is unsafe: if there's nothing to stash, the first command will do nothing, and then `stash pop` will unstash some random stuff from before.

Comment: Just to be extra clear: even if `git stash` does not stash anything it still "returns" no errorcode so the && will still continue with `git pull` and `git stash pop` and pop a previous stash. So better not use this unless you are very certain it will stash something!