# Git - error while merging because of local changes in master

Tags: git, version-control, merge

(in topicBranch)

```
git add .
git commit -m "added new feature"
git checkout master
git merger topicBranch
```

gives me the following error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Looking at the log, the file in question is just some breakpoint related file buried deeply within my `xcuserdata` directory.  My thinking was to run `git rm --cached path/to/that/file` and the problematic file would be removed from the index and git would have no problems with a merge. But it still fails.

My questions are A) how can I get the merge to run? B) given that git uses the "index" as its main area of interest, why wouldn't removing the problematic file from the index allow for a merge?

Comment: what all commands that you ran? can you modify your question with all commands that you fired with its sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not remove that file from the index, but reset it or stash it (meaning remove the local changes: the file is still needed in the index):

```
git stash
# or
git checkout -- your/file # overwrite any local change
# or, nuclear option
git reset --hard
```

---

If stashed, the normal workflow is to [`git stash pop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) after the merge.
(I actually prefer [pull.rebase + rebase.autostash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), that way git does stash for me on git pull)

> Uncommited changes that are stored in the stash can be taken out and applied to the original branch and other branches as well.

[image: https://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/img/post/stepup/capture_stepup1_3_3.png]

<sup>(source: "[Git Beginners Guide: Switching branches](https://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/stepup/stepup1_3.html)")</sup>

> This is where the git stash command comes into play. Like `git reset --hard`, **it gives you a clean working directory, but it also records your incomplete changes internally**.
>   After fixing the critical bug, you can re-apply these changes and pick up where you left off. You can think of `git stash` as a "pause button" for your in-progress work.

[image: https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/585/posts/22988/image/git-stash-stashing-changes.png]

<sup>(source: "[Quick Tip: Leveraging the Power of Git Stash](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-leveraging-the-power-of-git-stash--cms-22988)")</sup>

Comment: I wound up stashing the file and the branch was able to merge.  For clarification what is git doing when it "stashes" a file?  And why does imply the ability to merge my branch?

Comment: @user5797668 I have edited the answer to document git stash.