# Doing a partial pull

Tags: git

So a guy and I are working on a branch, and I've got some configuration files that only I use, something like this:

A-FILE 1 
A-FILE 2 
A-FILE 3 
B-FILE 1 
B-FILE 2

A-FILES 1-2-3 are files that I will later commit, but B-FILES 1-2 are files that only I need, I don't want to commit them nor stash them.

So, I need to make a pull now to update my project with the other guy's changes, but git tells me I can't because my changes over B-FILES 1-2 will be overwritten by the pull.

No idea what to do in these cases, any advice is welcome.

Comment: Why don't you want to stash them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want without stashing, but you can configure git to automaticaly stash before the pull and unstash after. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes), you have to have both `rebase.autoStash` and `pull.rebase` settings set to `true`. Then `git pull` will have the behavior you're looking for.