# Why won't --autostash option work ??? (used with git pull --rebase)

Tags: git

I use `git pull --rebase --autostash` all the time at work (in git bash, if that matters).

But for some reason, some of my colleagues can't get it to work, and now I discovered it doesn't work at home.

At home I'm using git 2.6.3 on a macbook.

The error message is simply : `` error: unknown option `autostash' ``

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That option is only valid for Git 2.9 (June 2016)

See "[Can “`git pull`” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)"

You can add a config

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, only a `git pull` is needed.

Comment: Indeed ! Thought it was a lot older than that. Thanks !