# Process to follow when i have changes and remote is ahead

Tags: git

I have made changes in my local repo, when I try to pull from master I get error like please commit your changes or else it would be lost.

Whats the ideal process in this case?

I saw something like `--rebase`.
What I am doing right now is taking a backup of my files and then updating and merging manually.

Is there a better way to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can commit your changes and then take a pull from master. This way, you will have all the changes you made and all the changes in master intact.

Comment: So, git pull will automatically merge the code if there is no conflict. Elase, just remove the conflicts and do a commit.

Answer (score 0):

> What I do now is take backup of my file and then take update and manually merge.
>   Is there a better way to this?

After "[Can “`git pull`” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)", you can simply do `git pull` (only for Git 2.9+, June 2016):

Add  the following config:

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, only a `git pull` is needed.

`git stash` will backup your files (local modifications).
Your local commits will be rebased on top of the upstream branches.
And your local changes (not yet committed) will be restored.

Comment: local changes not yet committed will be auto merged.

Comment: @Hacker yes, but they won't be committed for you: you can review the result of that auto-merge.