# Why there are commits like "Merge branch 'master' of" in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-code

### I wonder, why I see this commit in TFS:

[image]

### Here's what I've done:

1. I have changed these files

[image: my commit]

2. Meanwhile another developer made commit (`94feaf removed literal types from workflow/identity query as this comes from`) and pushed it

[image: another commit]

3. I have commited the changes localy (
   commit `a7de7a default value for root, ignored empty criteria`)  and clicked sync button in VS code. Sync does pull and push.
4. Why there is a commit `bcbb87 Merge branch 'master'` with exactly the same changes like `94feaf`?

   [image: merge commit]

Comment: Because a pull is shorthand for fetch and *merge*

Comment: But why do I need to merge, when I haven't changed the file?

Comment: Because you're syncing in changes from your other collaborator. If you want to avoid the merge commits, run `git pull --rebase` from the shell. I'm not sure if VS has that option in the GUI

Comment: Well, I guess that's the answer. If you write it as an answer with better explanation, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you would need a pull --rebase for avoid those merges.

But, as detailed in [this feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/10294356-sync-button-should-allow-git-pull-rebase):

> The "sync" button should respect the standard pull rebase setting for its default:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

But it does not:

> On our repo, we set option `pull.rebase = true`.
>   But inside Visual studio, it does a merge instead of a rebase as expected.
>   Please fix it.

Current situation:

[`git rebase` is supported in Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3697066-add-rebase-support-to-vs-tools-for-git)

> The feature can be found under the “`branches`” panel of the team explorer.

But:

> I'm not really sure to understand the reason behind "having a separate gesture for `pull` and `pull --rebase`".
>   I'll probably speak in the name of most developers: we expect something simple and clear. We all expect the "`Sync`" button to make a pull then a push. And we all expect that the pull command take into account the settings we set for our repos whether it's a merge or rebase.

---

[Since Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), I would recommend:

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

But again, those settings are not yet fully supported in Visual Studio.