# How to integrate local changes with changes on the remote repository in git?

Tags: git, github

I have a local project which is also present as a git repository.

Recently, me and my colleague worked on two different changes on the project. He modified some files and pushed it on the remote repository. I made some changes which are present in my local repository and do not conflict with any of his changes on the remote repository.

I need to first get his changes from remote repository and push my changes along with his that I just got to the remote repository. How do I do it?

Will something like - git pull origin master override my local changes with the current project on the remote repository?

Is there a way I can merge these commits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First commit your work via:

```
git add <path/to/file1>
git add <path/to/file2>
# ... etc. for each file
git commit -m 'commit message goes here'
```

Then you can either bring in his changes via merging:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Or you can rebase your work on the remote `master` branch:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git push origin master
```

In both cases, so long as you have committed your work, nothing will be lost.  Your commit will be there somewhere in your local `master` branch when you go to push to the remote repository.

Answer (score 4):

A `git pull --rebase` (meaning fetch+rebase) is the best practice.

It will replay your local commit on top of the updated `origin/master`.
Then `git push` will publish your commits.

If you have [Git 2.9 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), I would recommend:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a simple `git pull` is enough.