# Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, authentication, github

I have the following in my `.git/config`

```
  1 [core]
  2     repositoryformatversion = 0
  3     filemode = true
  4     bare = false
  5     logallrefupdates = true
  6 [remote "origin"]
  7     url = git@github.com:monajalal/instagram-scraper.git
  8     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

When I am trying to push the changes to the master I get this error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried these both but still get error:

```
2150  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/monajalal/instagram-scraper.git
 2154  git remote set-url origin git@github.com:monajalal/instagram-scraper.git


mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ git log
commit e69644389a5c7be65ae6eae14d74065e221600cb
Author: Mona Jalal <jalal@cs.wisc.edu>
Date:   Wed Mar 1 17:48:00 2017 -0600

    scrapy for instagram skeleton
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean


$ uname -a ; lsb_release -a
Linux pascal 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Please suggest fixes.

Comment: **"Permission denied (publickey)"**, Have you added your Public Key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in your GitHub Account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not the best solution but considering there was nothing in the repository I had created in github I used the following command and it worked out:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: I could have told you that would you have told me your error message

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain why you had to do a push -f. But again, when asking question on Stack Overflow, you cannot just mention "it didn't work". Adding the error message will help us help you.

Answer (score 8):

If you did not [properly setup your ssh key with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/), you can at least try with https (which you mentioned):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/monajalal/instagram-scraper.git
```

That will ask for your username (`monajalal`)/password of your GitHub account.

That will work because you own that repository, meaning you have the right to push.
Make sure you have made a commit locally in order to push.

```
git add .
git commit -m "new commit"

git push -u origin master
```

The fact that you might be forced to do a `git push -f` means the destination (the remote GitHub repo) is not empty but includes commits of its own (typically, a `README.md` or a `LICENSE` file)

In that case, it is best, with [Git 2.9 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), to do:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then

```
git pull
```

That will replay your local commits on top of those present in (and fetched form) the GitHub repo.

Then a simple `git push -u origin master` would work. No need to force push your history.