# git push to github in a batch job sumitted to a server using qsub

Tags: github, batch-processing

I set a ssh-agent and gave it an id_rsa key, so I don't have problem using git command on a terminal of a linux server to update to github, but when I try to do this by a bash script using qsub to submit the job to the server, I got the following error messages,

On branch master

nothing to commit, working directory clean

**Permission denied (publickey).**

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

my shell script is,

`#!/bin/bash
git add *.png
git commit -m "upload_fig"
git push`

I also set ~/.ssh/config like the following,

`Host remoteHost
    ForwardAgent yes`

`Host github
 HostName github.com
      User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? 
Thanks!

In addition: I have set id_rsa key to github and I can use git command on the local terminal.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for might be in what you are looking for might be in [this](http://what%20you%20are%20looking%20for%20might%20be%20in%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544568/permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository). I'm guessing you didn't add your public key, ~/.ssh/id_rsa, to your github account.

Comment: I did add my pubic key  ~/.ssh/id_rsa, to my github account. So that is why I can use git command to push figures to my github account by a terminal. But my problem is that the git commands in a qsub batch job script  doesn't work.

Comment: Did anything else from that question help?

Comment: Thank you so much. But my problem wasn't solved. Do you know how can a batch job to use the key recorded in a ssh-agent so that it can git push?