# how to push changes to github from a different computer

Tags: git, github

I'm always coming across this error message when trying to push to github from a different workstation.

```
To https://github.com/zentech/techgeorge.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/zentech/techgeorge.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

most of the time I work from different computers. (laptop/desktop) when I'm done and push my work. But when I move to my other computer. and I start making modifications. It asks me to fetch changes first before pushing to github

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Have you tried running `git pull` to bring your local git repository up to date?

Answer (score 0):

> It asks me to fetch changes first before pushing to github

This is expected. Before pushing, pull and rebase (if you have any un-pushed local changes) so that you get the latest code from upstream. More info is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) and [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

If it is a fork, [sync](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) (`fetch` + `checkout` + `merge`) your fork.

If you need to fetch all refs of all branches, do [`git pull --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

Answer (score 0):

> But when I move to my other computer. and I start making modifications

*Before* making any modification, start with `git pull`.

Even if you have made some modification and/or commits, you can still do a git pull, provided you have done (once) first (as [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global  rebase.autoStash true
```

That will fetch and then replay your local modification of top of the updated upstream branch.