# How can I merge remote branch to local branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

Our project has a develop branch. I created a bug-fix branch based on the develop branch, and changed one file a.java. And I know another people changed the a.java and merged to develop branch when I was fixing the bug.

Now I have fixed the bug, I want to merge my code to develop branch, but before I do that, I want to pull the changes(since other guy changed the a.java as well) to my local branch to test if it works, am I right?
How can I do it?

Firstly I pulled all the code by '**git pull**', and I am in my bug-fix branch.
then run '**git merge develop**', it output empty. Then I '**git merge origin/develop**'.It output below errors.

```
Updating 46f689b..3011608
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        projectA/a.java
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

How can I merge the develop branch to my working directory?Thanks.

Comment: Just follow the suggestion from the error message and either make a commit, or stash your work.

Answer (score 6):

Normally in this situation here is what I like to do,

```
git stash # Stash your local changes
git pull  # Update code
git stash apply # Merge your local changes
```

Now, for clarification, you can switch branch before your `git pull` if you need to synch another branch. From there you can come back on your bug-fixes branch and run `git stash apply` to then merge with your `develop` branch.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have some changes on that file

```
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

Just follow this:

```
# save current work state
git stash
# merge from develop
git merge origin/develop
# recover current work state (get the last item of stash)
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't push your local commits on the bug branch, you need to *rebase* them on top of the updated (by the other developer) `origin/bug` branch.

For that, make sure you have [set first the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309):

```
git --global config pull.rebase true
git --global config rebase.autoStash true
```

(to be done only once, from any folder)

Then, while you are in your current branch, you can include contribution of other with a simple:

```
git pull.
```

Now, make sure everything is committed, and:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
```

Finally, merge develop

```
git checkout bug
git merge develop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit or stash your changes to projectA/a.java before merging in other changes.

Commit Example:

```
$ git add projectA/a.java
$ git commit -m "my change message"
$ git pull origin/develop
```

Stash Example:

```
$ git stash
$ git pull origin/develop
$ git stash apply
```

Comment: He is asking how merge, not how to pull