# git term for downloading and updating local working copy

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

What is git term for downloading new data from a remote repository in order to update your local working copy files?

I am talking about `git fetch & git merge` or `git pull`, is there are specific git term for this operation?  I know what these commands do and mean but I am looking for correct git term for this operation.

I have heard of '*pulling*' but that is confused often with '*pull request*'.

I have also heard of '*reverse engineering*' which is even more confusing to me.

What is correct term?

Comment: The term for `git fetch` is fetch.  The term for `git pull` is pull.  The fact that people conflate the idea of "pull request" with the git term "pull" is not git's fault - the hosting software that coined the term pull request (as it is used today) came along later and could've chosen a more distinct name.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yea, I though so but I got confused with the 'reverse engineering' term one of my coworker used to use.  I tried googling and wasnt able to find that relating to git so I think he got it confused but wanted to check.  Thanks Mark

Comment: Reverse engineering isn't git specific and usually means _"is the process by which a man-made object is deconstructed to reveal its designs, architecture [etc]"_.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pull` should be enough.
It involves:

- fetching: updating the remote tracking branches in your local repo

  - merging: merging a remote tracking branch to a local branch.
  - or rebasing: replaying your local commits on top of the remote tracking branch.
    [Since Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), `git pull` can do a rebase behind the scene.

Note that [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) is a remote operation (on the server side).
And is not always called "pull request". GitLab calls it "[merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/merge_requests/)"