# WIP on master: Auto stash before merge of "master" and "origin/master"

Tags: git, gitkraken

I'm using Gitkraken, sometimes I see the message below.

```
WIP on master: Auto stash before merge of "master" and "origin/master"
```

What it really means? It usually occurs after I try PULL. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "git pull" automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that, when you started your git pull, you had some modifications which weren't committed.

In this case, git stashes them before pulling, and will reapply them afterwards.

If no extra message appears afterwards : all is good.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your local changes would be compromised by the merge implied by your `git pull` and they're automatically stashed beforehand.

If you prefer to avoid this mechanism to kick in, be sure to stash your changes manually yourself or commit them before pulling.