# How to clone Github repository to local device with Github Desktop

Tags: xcode, github, push, git-commit, pull

I have a project my friend and I are working on. He made some changes and added them to the project on github. I hit clone on the project in github and then it opened up the github desktop and now I have 1 arrow pointing up and 16 pointing down.

[image]

I believe this means I have a non-committed change and 16 changes ready to be pulled, but no idea how to find this change, or if I commit the change will it take away all the changes already on github that are not on local yet?

Just don't want everything to just be deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a non-committed change and 16 changes ready to be pulled, but no idea how to find this change,

Committed change actually: you have one local commit.

You can:

- do a backup of your local repository
- make sure you have autostash and rebase in place
- then pull through the GitHub Desktop interface.

That is ([Git 2.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```