# Git refuses to pull after .gitignore change

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Git won't allow me to pull some commits. I must add that one of those commits has a `.gitignore` change adding some files to it.

When I try to pull the commits it says that I have local changes to the same files that were added to `.gitignore`. *but* I cannot find any local changes, `git status`, `git diff`, source tree, all show no local change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have added files to .gitignore, make sure to have remove them as well, otherwise they would still be tracked.

```
git rm --cached -- anIgnoredFile
git commit -m "record file deletion/ignore"
```

Second, when you pull, try a rebase instead of a merge, [which you can automate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309) with:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global  rebase.autoStash true
```

Then try again your `git pull`: this time it should re-apply your local changes on top of the updated history.