# how to automate the “stash-and-pull” process? (git)

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-pull, git-stash

I create a shell script for run project in a local environment. When running the script I need include if git update also updates my local code with git code before run project.

```
cd /var/www/html/project && \
    git stash && \
    git pull && \
    git stash apply
```

There is my try. But problem their when conflict happens no way to change conflict. I need when git stash apply if conflict happen stop a script make way to resolve conflict.

Comment: `git pull` already has an [`--autostash` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash). It stops if the `git pull` part triggers a conflict, and leaves your stashed changes in the stash. Is this the behavior you are looking for ?

Comment: note : this option was added pretty recently to git, you may need to update your local `git` to version 2.27 to have this option. A more detailed history for this option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/86072)

Comment: Yes, that is I'm looking for. But a problem there when conflicts happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` or `git stash apply` will exit with an error code (= an exit code different from '0') if a conflict occurs.

In bash, the last command's exit code is stored in `$?` :

```
exitCode=$?
if [ $exitCode -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "*** something errored"
    exit $exitCode
fi
```