# Why stash all command won't work in command line (Windows): git --git-dir=c/a.git --work-tree=c/b status -a?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying below git command referring to this documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git.
It works fine if I use `stash` instead `stash -a` in below git command, else it shows error message mentioned below. Can anyone help me with the alternatives to make it work per my need?

My requirement is to stash all files including untracked (if any) before I want to take a git pull, I have multiple projects, for which I want to automate this task because for each project repeating `git stash -a`, then `git pull origin master-ci` is the headache, somehow I want to automate this in `git-pull-latest.bat` script.

**Git command tried:**

```
set MY_REPO=C:\Users\ravibeli\Documents\Projects\GitRepo
set MY_GIT_OPERATION=pull origin master-ci

git --git-dir=%MY_REPO%\demo-service\.git --work-tree=%MY_REPO% stash -a && git --git-dir=%MY_REPO%\demo-service\.git --work-tree=%MY_REPO% %MY_GIT_OPERATION%
```

**Error message:**

```
Ignoring path demo-service/
Saved working directory and index state WIP on poc-branch: 9f625aa18 Merge pull request #1004 in demo-service from ~ravibeli/demo-service:display-message to poc-branch
```

Comment: It's probably a bug in `git stash`, which has been undergoing some internal rewrites, mainly because of Windows. If you have a reliable reproducer and a specific Git version number, you can send a bug report to the Git mailing list. Meanwhile, I suspect using `git -C %MYREPO% stash -a` will work. As a bonus, this command is shorter.

Comment: In general, though, I recommend *avoiding* `git stash`, especially in scripts. The behavior of `git stash` is not easy to predict. If you want to automate a build, do that in a "clean" environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying and automate stash expicitely, you could [activate autostash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

But if you do not want to rebase on each pull, and do want the classic `fetch`+`merge` done by a regular `git pull`, you can set with Git 2.27:

```
git config --global merge.autostash true
```

In both cases, a `git pull` will first stash any work in progress from your current working tree.