# How to resync local master to remote master?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-pull

The master branch in my local repo is showing a push badge with increasing numbers.  I know it is up-to-date with the remote master, because all changes in local branches have been pulled and merged into the remote master.  But every time I fetch and pull from the remote to update my local repo, the local master appears to be ahead of the remote by one more commit.  But I know the two masters are identical.

(not sure how all this started, I may have done a forced push to the origin, at somepoint...?)

Would  `'git pull --rebase origin master'`  help get the local master match the remote?  Or would it it be `git reset --hard remote/master` ?

And how could I avoid the two branches getting out of sync again?

Comment: Actually, `git pull --rebase` would _cause_ the observations you are seeing, namely that your local `master` appears to be some number of commits ahead of the remote.  You might want to include the exact steps which are happening here.

Comment: Does a `git pull` create a merge commit locally? This could explain the extra commit your seeing. This is often seen when working together on the same branch without rebase pulling.

Comment: Every time I make changes to one of the local branches, I pull it to the corresponding remote branch and and merge it to the remote master.  Then I do a fetch in the local repo, which then shows that a pull is needed by the local master to get the change from the remote master.  I've not been doing local merges.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `git config pull.rebase` is set to true, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309).

That would means any `git pull` would actually replay your un-pushed local commits on top of the updated remote `origin/master` tracking branch.
If the local history seems correct, a simple `git push` should resolve the issue.

Comment: The local and remote masters are the same.  When I try to push the local master to the remote, I get an a message that looks like a text picture of guy in sunglasses and this: "remote: Branch refs/heads/master can only be modified through pull requests. remote: Check your branch permissions configuration with the project administrator."

Comment: @alfavictor Are you pushing to gitHub, GitLab? BitBucket? An on-premise instance, or a .com service?

Comment: I'm pushing to BitBucket