# What is the best practice to keep local changes during a git rebase without a commit?

Tags: git

I have made changes to certain files (docker-init etc) for debugging purposes and I don't intend to push those changes to master.

Whenever I do a rebase, I either need to stash my changes or do a commit and later undo it. This is a bit tedious to be honest.

I don't want git to track changes on those files but I can't add the files to `gitignore` as they might be removed from the master branch. Or can I?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes — does this answers your question?

Comment: If the files are not tracked by git and are not overwritten by the rebase, you don't need to do anything.  If `git stash` and `git stash pop` are too tedious, I suggest you have an unrealistic view of tedium!

Comment: Make a shell function: `pull() { git stash; git pull -r; git stash pop; }`

Comment: Or you do commit those changes. That doesn't mean that you have to push them.

Comment: following @mkrieger1's comment : you may at least keep these changes in a side branch, so that if you (accidentally or willingly) discard these changes, getting them back becomes as simple as `git cherry-pick my/debugging/changes` (I'm all against tediousness too, I aliased `git` to `g` and `cherry-pick` to `cp` ;) )

Comment: Very helpful comments, thanks all!