# Made changes in local repository before pulling it from online repo. will there be loss of data after i pull?

Tags: git, github

I opened my previous changes of my files that was pushed to online git repo and started editing them.

When I hit push it told me to pull and work before pushing to online repo again.
But I already made changes to the files and it is a pain to do it again from start.

So if I pull the online repo files to my local repo which is already edited, will the changes get lost and will I have to start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (fast-forward) pull itself may fail on a conflict or the branches being simply out of sync (which will create a merge commit). What you can do is issuing a rebase together with the pull:

```
git pull --rebase
```

which will prioritize the changes in the remote repo and apply your changes *on top of those*.

Or you can divide the work by

- creating a new branch from your local one (e.g. as a backup): `git checkout -b backup`
- re-create the original branch: `git branch -D master; git checkout origin/master; git checkout -b master`
- then rebase your backup on top of it: `git checkout backup; git rebase master`

Or play with [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to pull only specific commits.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

- first, add and commit your work in progress: no matter what you do next, you will always be able to find back that commit.
- then modify your configuration (if you are [using Git 2.27+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

  ```sh
  git config --global pull.rebase true
  git config --global rebase.autoStash true
  ```
- finally, a simple `git pull` is enough.

No need for `git pull --rebase`: it will be done for you.

That will:

- pull new commits from remote rpeository
- replay your local commits (your work in progress) on top of it.

you might have conflicts to resolve, but that is the all point: resolve those conflicts locally, before pushing back your work to the remote repository.

Comment: I pulled the project accidently to my local repo but changes were present and nothing was lost. but i will use the methods u guys told from now on. ... thankyou for you help....