# Issue using GitHub from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I am using Xcode version 12.5 and want to push a demo app to GitHub.

Though I have used GitHub to upload iOS apps in the past; it was a while ago and I needed a mind refresher so I followed these tutorials: [How To Use GitHub with Xcode 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v25er68nnk8) and [How to upload Xcode project to GitHub (Working with Git)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHEuUHqLvRk), hoping it would be OK for my use case.

Also taking a look [here to review my GitHub knowledge](https://tutorama.info/CTG/Git).

But when I try to push my project from Xcode I keep getting this message:

The given URL 'git+ssh://git@github.com:me/MyRepo.git' is invalid.

Provide a valid URL and try again.

although my repository is created. What am I missing?

.......
Some more information follows.

Here is what happens when I try a pull:

```
MacBook-Air$ git pull origin master
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile     divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by    running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the    default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward    only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config     --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also     pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override    the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
MacBook-Air$
```

Comment: Try `git remote set-url origin git@github.com: com:me/MyRepo.git`

Comment: This worked for me a few minutes ago, `git remote add origin https://username:access-token@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: I tried to follow these advices, one after the other. In both cases I get this new message:
"The local repository is out of date.
Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again."

Comment: Since the local repository is actually the only content I have, I am not sure how it can be out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git+ssh://` might not be correctly interpreted by XCode, while a regular SSH URL (git@github.com:me/myRepo) or HTTPS one would work.

If you are using HHTPS, don't forget to activate `git config credential.helper` (you should see `osxkeychain`) in order to cache your PAT(Personal Access Token), instead of putting it in clear text in your URL.

Finally, do a `git fetch` and see what `git status` returns.
And `git push`, or, if you are sure your local history is the right one, `git push --force` (assuming you are the only one working on that repository).

Another approach (with [Git 2.6+, Sep. 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

If you care about the remote (GitHub) history, then:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autostash true
git pull
```

That will automatically replay your local commits on top of the updated (fetched) remote tracking branch `origin/<yourBranch>`

Comment: Thanks. You mention "git config credential.helper". Is this a command to run in the terminal?

Comment: I have run the command and get osxkeychain. But for the rest, trying to follow your suggestions, I still get the message mentioned in a previous comment: "The local repository is out of date. Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again."

Comment: @Michel OK. What happen when you pull?

Comment: I added some information to the post so you can see the result of a pool. I am not using GitHub very often and it seems like I am missing a few important details in terms of configuration.

Comment: @Michel If you care about the remote (GitHub) history, then: `git ocnfig --global pull.rebase true`, `git config --global rebase.autostash true`. And finally `git pull`.

Comment: I followed your tips as well as corrected a mistake on my part (I was using a wrong branch name) and it finally works. Thanks a lot. I accepted your answer, though in fact as much as the answer it is the comments I want to accept.

Comment: @Michel Well done. I have included the comment in the answer for more visibility.