# How can I push the local repo changes to remote repo and remote has already updated files which I don't have?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

How can I push the local repo changes to remote repo and remote has already updated files which I don't have? We are working in a team so continuously there are changes that need to be pulled first but unfortunately, my code gets disappeared when I pull it.

I am using the following commands:
In order to PUSH

```
git add .
git commit -m 'msg'
git push -u origin development
! [rejected]        development -> development (fetch first)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gsesltd/metis_maza.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

In order to PULL:

```
git pull origin development
```

My files get updated and all my written code is gone now. Thanks to git reset that I have my code.

Can somebody please tell me how can I push the code without force push + I want to have all the remote updates too? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to minimize any "code disappearance" on pull, do a rebase instead: that would replay your own local commits *on top of* fetched commits from the remote repository.

Since [Git 2.6 (Q3 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), type:

```sh
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a simple git pull will at least put your commits on top.