# How to update git for sources you've been working on since Clone?

Tags: git

How to update git for sources you've been working on since Clone?

I cloned project A and continued development.
In this state, a lot of commits in project A have accumulated, and I want to reflect all files committed in project A other than the source I worked on in my source code.

What command to run to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use and the global configuration ([Git 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a simple git pull is enough:

- it will stash your work in progress
- replay your local commits on top of the updated (fetched) upstream branch
- reapply your stashed work