# Pull latest changes from remote and push my changes as latest over it

Tags: java, git

I am new to git, I have a use case, where I have raised the new commit and send it to code review, but then I realise my local mainline branch is not to the latest commit, someOne in my team had push the new commit to the remote mainline branch.

Let see the scanriao:

A--> B--> C
<-- my local latest commit at C.

But My team raise the new commit and merged it to remote branch.Let say it is commit D.

So What I wanted to acheive is given below:

A-->B-->D--->C

HoW I can acheived above digram change. Like pull the latest changes from mainline(i.e D) and then push my changes(i.e C) as a latest commit over it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch` syncs the latest master.

After that in your branch run `git rebase -i origin/master`.

After rebasing push your branch to remote `git push --force`.

Now your branch aligns with `master` and your commit is the latest in the chain.

IMO it's OK to use `git push --force` in your branch (if you develop alone in there), but it's not OK to use it on master so be careful with that.

Comment: when I run `git fetch`, and then `git log`, it does't show the commit name that my team push it to remote branch ?

Comment: Do the rebase. Then it shows.

Answer (score 2):

I always use  (since [Git 2.6, Q3 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309))

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, a simple `git pull` is enough to get `A-->B-->D--->C` automagically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Option

   stash your changes and take pull then apply you changes (and resolve conflicts
   if occur) and push code.
2. Option

   git fetch syncs the latest master.
   After that in your branch run git rebase -i origin/master.
   After rebasing push your branch to remote git push --force.
   Now your branch aligns with master and your commit is the latest in the chain.
   by @tarmo

Comment: Stashing only works if you have not commited anything yet.