# How to proceed with git push when getting "rejected" and "<filename>: needs merge"?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

Within project, someone pushed new files, I didn't pull them, then I've added new files, commited and then tried to push it to main.

```
git push -u origin main
```

Returns

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
```

Then `git checkout main`

Gives me

```
README.md: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

How to solve conflict and proceed with my push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to open `README.md` and remove the merge markers, choosing in the process which contribution side you want to keep.

Then add, and commit.

Make sure you have set (with [Git 2.6+, Sept. 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)):

```sh
git config --global rebase.autosquash true
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

From there, a simple `git pull` will replay your own commits on top of `origin/main`. Resolve conflicts, if there are any.
And push.