Cannot pull with rebase, how to get changes wtihout stash

git pull --tags origin development
error: Cannot pull with rebase, you have unstaged changes.
error: please commit or stash them.

i want to keep my changes and pull at the same time. I dont want stash. How to achieve on visual studio code editor, there should be a settings for it.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes

If you cannot rebase at this time, you could use git fetch instead of git pull. It will update the local repo without touching your working copy.

Why don't you want to stash? That's the easiest. Just stash, pull, then pop your stash.

I would ask: why don't you want to stash?

You have these 4 alternatives: commit your changes, stash, remove changes, don't pull. If for whatever reasons you don't you want to stash the next method to try is: commit your changes, pull with rebase, verify that you commit is still at the tip of the branch, apply the changes and remove the commit.

i need to open android and ios simulator at the same time with same auth token, stashing ruins my development enviroment

will try to git fetch, thanks for all replies.
