# Two parallel branches in Git, how to work on "future" but commit basic fixes to "master"

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

*This is probably a common scenario but there are so many Git workflow questions here on SO that I couldn't find an answer for my exact question. Which is:*

I have a `master` and `future` branches in Git that live in parallel. `future` contains some future features while `master` is the current version (approximately).

When developing a future feature, I often encounter a situation where I need to make a fix that needs to go to master. What I do now:

1. Stash work in progress in `future`
2. Switch to `master`
3. Fix code in `master`
4. Switch to `future`
5. Merge from `master`
6. Stash pop

In some cases, where the fix is better tested in the `future` branch, the process becomes even more cumbersome, consisting of making the change in `future`, committing it there, switching to master, cherry-picking from future, checking out future, reseting future and merging from master in the end.

There must be a better way but I can't figure it out. Approaches that wouldn't work (I believe; correct me if I'm wrong):

- Merging from `future` to `master`. I don't want all commits from future in master.
- Committing everything to `future` and then cherry-picking certain commits to `master`. This *alone* would not be enough because future merges from `master` to `future` would cause duplicate commits (or maybe even conflicts?). Maybe I could create opposite commits in `future` to those cherry-picked to `master` but that feels messy.

How do people deal with this workflow?

Comment: Hi have you found a solution for your problem? I hit a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210198/cherry-pick-a-commit-to-master-seems-unavoidable-in-my-case-how-do-i-mitigate-i

Comment: @Qiulang I now prefer feature toggles over long-running Git branches.

Answer (score 2):

If you are alone developing on the `future` branch, you could rebase it on top of `master` instead of merging master to it.

And since git 1.8.4 (July 2013), [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) has learned to "autostash": see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284754/6309).

```
git checkout future
git rebase --autostash master
```

For the opposite case, cherry-pick remains the main option.

Comment: "For the opposite case, cherry-pick remains the main option." Do you mean that I should commit to `future` and later cherry-pick to `master`? Does Git remember from where it cherry-picked so that later commits are not affected by the possible duplicity? Or should I revert commits in `future` that got cherry-picked to `master`?

Comment: @Borek that is the main issue of cherry-picking: it adds duplication (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309). I would prefer, if possible to rebase interactive future, in order to put first those commits (and merge to master those first commits of the future re-oredered branch), instead of using cherry-picking.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Stash work in progress in future
> 2. Switch to master
> 3. Fix code in master
> 4. Switch to future
> 5. Merge from master
> 6. Stash pop
>
> There must be a better way but I can't figure it out.

I used to do that process, but after I found I needed to do switch back and forth often, I changed to simply having 2 working directories - one for working on "master" branch and one for "future" branch ("develop" in my case). Both dirs used the same remote repo/origin and the two working dirs had each other as remotes too.  Two dirs eliminated the need to stash save/pop before/after switching branches.

I also didn't feel the need to pull the fix from master into future (step 5) right away unless there was a reason I had too.  Normally, I would finish the current feature for future first and delay merging from master until convenient.

Comment: That's a reasonable workflow, and certainly useful for some scenarios. My trouble is that I need to merge those `master` changes almost immediately so that's still quite a PITA. (I might leave the branching model entirely and use some other technique like feature toggles.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new branch for the fix.

- Merge it in master
- Merge it in your branch if it's not convenient to do it at that very
  moment directly to master.
- Other developers could merge it in their own branches.